# Recover project added in tfs after TFS 11.0 (2012) server crash

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Team foundation server 2021. I do take backup of all TFS databases regularly. So now in case of disaster recovery (in case full machine gets crash) how can i use this backup to recover TFS and all collection etc. I want easy and the best approach .

I have seen so many articles in microsoft website but nothing is really so helpful and difficult to understand. So please suggest a better tutorial or procedure to do it

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have TFS2012 Update 1 (there is no 2011 version). You should upgrade to TFS2012.2 which has the Scheduled Backups feature included.

Comment: should I get problem for current code while migrating from "TFs 2012 update 1" to TFS2012.2 . i.e whether TFS2012.2 will carry all the check in-check out . please help me. I am newer to this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: No; you shouldn't have any problems with the check-in/out processes after the upgrade. But keep in mind that the last update available is Update 4.
Update 2 is the first update that has the backup feature integrated.

Answer (score 0):

When taking a backup of a running TFS instance **always** backup all databases. In cases of a disaster situation the only way to recover, is to restore **all** databases and re-run the TFS Application Tier install.

There is ample guidance available, plus the Backup tool that was introduced in the product with TFS 2012.2 is also available for older versions (2012 rtm and update 1) as part of the [Team Foundation Power tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775).

The guidance you should follow is that for either:

- [restore TFS to the same location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252458(v=vs.100).aspx) (in case the server name for TFS and SQL remain teh same)
- [restore TFS to a new server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252458(v=vs.100).aspx) (in case the server name for TFS or SQL has changed)